# Escaping in test comparisons

Tags: shell, variables, comparison, escaping

In the following, I would like check if a given variable name is set:

```
$ set hello
$ echo $1
hello
$ echo $hello

$ [[ -z \$$1 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

Since `$hello` is unset, I would expect the test to return `true`. What's wrong here? I would assume I am escaping the dollar incorrectly.
TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing if `\$$1` is empty. Since it begins with a `$`, it is not empty. In fact, `\$$1` expands to the string `$hello`.

You need to tell the shell that you want to treat the value of `$1` as the name of a parameter to expand.

- With bash: `[[ -z ${!1} ]]`
- With zsh: `[[ -z ${(P)1} ]]`
- With ksh: `tmp=$1; typeset -n tmp; [[ -z $tmp ]]`
- Portably: `eval "tmp=\$$1"; [ -z "$tmp" ]`

(Note that these will treat unset and empty identically, which is usually the right thing.)

Comment: Another way in `ksh`: `typeset -n tmp; tmp=$1; [[ -z $tmp ]] ...` (I like to avoid `eval` as much as possible (even though it's safe in this particular circumstance).

Comment: @Dennis: thanks, it's good to know there's a way in ksh too (and I don't like `eval` either, but it's the only portable way).